# Can I specify that an Array is not assignable to Record?

Tags: arrays, typescript, record

I have a member of type `Record<number, MyType>`. Currently, I can also assign an Array to it. I get it: an Array is an object (`typeof [] => 'object'`) and the indices are the keys. Is it, however, possible to tell the compiler that I don't want to allow arrays to be passed to my variable(s) of type `Record<int, WhateverType>`?

```
const myRecord: Record<number, MyType> = []; // <= would like to have an error here
```

Comment: Array is a Record indexed by number, what is then wrong with that assignment for you?

Comment: @MaciejSikora It misleads the other developers into thinking that a record with sequential indices is viable when the structure is more of a lookup.

Comment: What is `int`?  Is it a small `bigint`? 

Comment: @jcalz Oops! Old habits, you know... That's like 10% of my compiler errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A custom `NumberRecord` type can exclude an array by enforcing, that no `length` property exists (analogue to [`ArrayLike`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/48fa3a5f18a7090a7b3fb8836159fee7e48a8013/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1433) built-in declaration):

```
const t = {
  0: "foo",
  1: "bar"
}

const tArr = ["foo", "bar"]

type NumberRecord<T> = {
  length?: undefined; // make sure, no length property (array) exists
  [n: number]: T;
}

const myRecordReformed1: NumberRecord<string> = tArr; // error
const myRecordReformed2: NumberRecord<string> = t // works
```

[Code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=14&ssc=59&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBLC8MDeAoG6YAYBcMBEAZiCHgDRoYCMueARgIYBOeKAviiqJLFAIKOMYiANqFiZfA2YBdDlACeABwCmMAHIBXALa1ljAErLQjACYAeACoA%20IcgrpGy%20ifAAbeTFfKwAcygALAH5cDTATZQIASzBlEwBuGAB6RJgtegBrVQgNR1IYMBBPbz9-GEVGEBVGBRgACiZGenkAShhlAA9I6Ah7GEdnNw9hMFwwbV1GaVwLOLYOLmhU%20UNjE0MiRi1Y6nVxvRWQUzNoRmifG0Q%20AQTktoFDznBFrWWjQ7WIw62TACZcTR0%20zeRxOZwucCSKQA7od0hAgA)

Comment: What's the reason for `readonly` on the key? I had to remove it, as it doesn't allow dynamically adding new entries (i.e. `myRecordReformed2[5] = "nope";`).

Comment: Good catch, that was just code copied from the `ArrayLike` type. It isn't relevant here, dropped it from the answer.